# In picturefill.js, how to write other than the above specified?

Tags: css, picturefill

**In picturefill.js, how to write other than the above specified?**

In the following, what to write and how do the conditions specified that other than the above (less than the screen width 480px)?

※I want to specify the thumb.jpg

---

**Some to the difference between writing pattern A and the pattern B?**

Which is correct?

---

Pattern A

```
<picture>
 <!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->
 <source srcset="main.jpg" media="(min-width: 480px)">
 <!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
 <img srcset="thumb.jpg" alt="">
</picture>
```

---

Pattern B

```
<picture>
 <!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->
 <source srcset="main.jpg" media="(min-width: 480px)">
 <source srcset="thumb.jpg">
 <!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
 <img srcset="thumb.jpg" alt="">
</picture>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically they are both correct*, and functionally equivalent, but A is preferable because the `source` element is completely unnecessary, since it repeats the same information already specified in `img`.

*) with the exception that `src` is a required attribute on `img`, but that is an intended violation when using picturefill in order to avoid double download in legacy browsers.